# List of web applications or web sites for language learning

Tags: webapp-rec

What are popular or maybe not so popular (but also useful) web applications, which center around the theme of language learning?

Answer (score 3):

BBC has a comprehensive [language learning site](http://www.bbc.co.uk/languages/). 36 different languages!

Answer (score 2):

Check out [LiveMocha](http://www.livemocha.com)

> Livemocha is the world's largest
>   online language learning community! 6
>   million Livemocha members appreciate
>   our simple, effective approach to
>   language learning: the most natural
>   way to learn a language is with help
>   from real native speakers.from real native speakers.

Comment: did you have a chance to use it? is it any good?

Comment: I completed the Icelandic section. Livemocha's computer based training part is extremely easy and reasonably paced.  It is good if you are learning your first word.  If you have a semester in a language, it is too easy.

The other strength of Livemocha is the chat functions, where you can collaborate with other users (fluent people help you with language X, you help people with English) on translating the exercises.

Comment: Alas, they've closed free courses. There are only basic vocabulary lessons now.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [smart.fm](http://smart.fm/)

It is not strictly for language learning as it covers all different subjects but it has pretty good [resources on languages](http://smart.fm/goals/search?keyword=language).

The content is partially created by smart.fm itself but the large part of it is created by the user community. I went through [SAT Verbal](http://smart.fm/goals/700)  programme to work on my English vocabulary and I found it pretty good. My favourite feature of the app is the fact it organises the repetitions for you.

They also have an [iPhone app](http://smart.fm/iphone) which is a bit limited at the moment but allows you to do some learning on the go and can be used off-line.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Wikimedia's [wikibooks.org](http://en.wikibooks.org), they have [quite a good set of language books](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Subject%3aLanguages).

Answer (score 0):

[Babbel](http://www.babbel.com) is a good one which just recently supports voice recognition. The voice recognition wasn't that great when I tried it out, but it looks good nonetheless. Only for a few European languages though.

Answer (score 0):

There is a site [lang-8.com](http://lang-8.com/) (that's "lang-infinity" apparently, rather than "lang-eight") which might suit you, as well as [italki.com](http://www.italki.com/).

Answer (score 0):

EduFire - http://edufire.com/ - is good. It is also not exclusive for languages, but it has some tools for that purpose, such as the flashcards for vocabulary.

Answer (score 0):

I thought this guy has an amazing little video about the different options out there: 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tYO5aw4wPHE&feature=fvw

Answer (score 0):

Try http://www.babelreader.com It allows you to directly read foreign language blogs and websites. It keeps track of the words you know and the words you are learning. You can export words and marked phrases to Anki for review. It is better to read about something you are into than dry school textbooks. The drawback is that you need to find the blogs you are interested in by yourself. Non an easy task in the language you don't know yet.